# Find the $\lim\limits _{x\to1}\frac{x^3+x-2}{\sin\pi x}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find the limit $$\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{x^3+x-2}{\sin\pi x}$$
I would like to solve the problem without the L'Hôpital's rule. I am also not really familiar with the asymptotic analysis (asymptotic notation).

We can see that $x=1$ is a root of the polynomial in the numerator, and it factors as $(x-1)(x^2+x+2)$. So it's the only real root.

I don't really see how to use the limit of $\dfrac{\sin f(x)}{f(x)}$ when $f(x)$ approaches $0$ (the limit is $1$), as in our problem the argument $\pi x$ of the sine when $x$ approaches $1$ doesn't approach $0$, but $\pi\ne0$. Also how can we get a factor $\pi x$ in the numerator? Is there a general approach for problems of this kind?

Comment: HInt: your factorization shows the limit is $-\frac{4}{\pi}\lim_{y\to0}\frac{y}{\sin y}$ with $y:=\pi(1-x)$.

Comment: @J.G., I am not sure I understand. Where did the factor $(x^2-x+2)$ (in the numerator) go? How do we come up with $y:=\pi(1-x)$?

Comment: A factor with a finite nonzero limit can be moved outside. I then transformed to exploit a famous limit.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{x^3+x-2}{\sin\pi x} &= \lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{(x-1)(x^2+x+2)}{\sin[\pi(x-1)+\pi]} \\
&= \lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{(x-1)\cdot4}{-\sin[\pi(x-1)]} \\
&= -4\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{x-1}{\sin\pi(x-1)} \\
&= -\frac{4}{\pi}\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{\pi(x-1)}{\sin\pi(x-1)} \\
&= -\frac{4}{\pi}\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{y}{\sin y} \\
&= -\frac{4}{\pi}\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{1}{\frac{\sin y}{y}} \\
&= -\frac{4}{\pi}\dfrac{1}{\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin y}{y}} = -\frac{4}{\pi}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Using the substitution $y=x-1$ you have

$$\begin{array} 
 \\\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{x^3+x-2}{\sin\pi x}& \\
=\lim_{x\to1} \dfrac{(x-1)(x^2+x+2)}{\sin\pi x}&\\
=\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{y(y^2+3y+4)}{\sin\pi (y-1)}&\\
=\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{y(y^2+3y+4)}{\sin(\pi y-\pi)}&\\
=\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\pi}{\pi}\cdot \dfrac{y(y^2+3y+4)}{-\sin\pi y}&\\
=\lim_{y\to0}-\dfrac{y\pi}{\sin\pi y}\cdot \dfrac{(y^2+3y+4)}{\pi}&\\
=-1\cdot \dfrac 4{\pi}=-\dfrac 4{\pi}
\end{array}$$

Comment: $\sin(\pi(y-1))=\sin(\pi y-\pi)=-\sin\pi y$.

Comment: @J.G. Ah it is true. I am done a mistake. Grazieeeeeeeeeeeeeeee